# Since, resistance is a passive element, so why its value comes out to be negative?

Tags: network, circuit-theory

In thevenin's theorm,

In a circuit with current dependent current source (value=2i, pointing downwards), in parallel with 2 resistors in parallel i.e 2ohm and 4ohm. And current "i" in 2ohm resistor arm( pointing upwards)

By calculating Thenvin resistance, it comes out to be -4 ohm. But as resistance is a passive element and absorb power. But as per negative value of R, it says it is supplying power, which is practically impossible. Why it is so?

Comment: Because ideal current sources don't actually exist.

Comment: Then, what does it mean? Why is the resistance come out to be negative? Is the circuit supplying power, then?

Comment: No, it means that your circuit will never exist in reality.

Comment: As a side note, there is a schematic button available when you write your question. That would be more efficient than a textual description.

Comment: How can the gain of an op-amp be -Rf/Rin. It's all in the detail.

Comment: Since apples are fruit, why does the number of apples come out to be negative with I subtract 3 from 2?

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind. I know it is a bit simple question to ask, but still it clears my doubt and also help others to understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing several things

a) A resistor, a physical passive element that absorbs power

b) A resistance, the mathematical ratio of voltage to current, that can be written for real resistors *and* for **any** situation where a voltage and current can be defined

c) An abstract ideal model containing elements that can supply power, like current sources, which can sometimes be useful, to the extent that they describe well the situation you are trying to understand.

If you connect an abstract current controlled current source with an arbitrary transfer ratio to a resistor or two, and then pick out out a random voltage and take its ratio to a non-specific current, you should not be surprised to get an arbitrary resistance, including negative.

Comment: Thank you sir. Now, I have got it. I was just confused when my resistance came out to be negative, but now my doubt is clear.